# How to find the data from the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

First, I apologize asking about the code that I didn't understood. Here is the code that is currently used to find from the array. In this code there is a function `findProducts(p)`. I am confused about the way this function is being called `this.findProducts, [p.id]`.

Can anybody please help me, I am a complete beginner in `JavaScript`.

Thank You.

```
  products = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.products = this.getProducts();
  }
  getProducts() {
    return [
      { 'id': '1', 'title': 'Screw Driver', 'price': 400, 'stock': 11 },
      { 'id': '2', 'title': 'Nut Volt', 'price': 200, 'stock': 5 },
      { 'id': '3', 'title': 'Resistor', 'price': 78, 'stock': 45 },
      { 'id': '4', 'title': 'Tractor', 'price': 20000, 'stock': 1 },
      { 'id': '5', 'title': 'Roller', 'price': 62, 'stock': 15 },
    ];
  }

  updateStock(p) {
    console.log(p); //{id: "1", updatedStockValue: 23}
    console.log("final", this.products.find(this.findProducts, [p.id]));
  }

  findProducts(p) {
    console.log(p); //{id: "1", title: "Screw Driver", price: 400, stock: 11…}
    console.log(this); //["1"]

    return p.id === this[0];
  }
```

Comment: is this code really working? Can you console `this` inside the `findProducts` & check its value?

Comment: yes the code is working inside that function value p is {id: "1"
price: 400
stock: 11
title: "Screw Driver"} and this is ["1"]

Comment: Not sure how `findProducts` will get its value

Comment: @brk https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcu5qf this is the one I am practing

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a `Array.find(function(element(){})` function that you can use to look up values in an array, and inside the `function(element){}` you define the matching criteria .

Here the parameter to the Array.find() function is passed as the `function(element)`, in this case, `findProducts()`, and additional parameters to the find function is given as another argument following the comma (in this case `p.id`).

You can pass any number of arguments while calling the function, and they'll all be accessible using an array indexing approach. For example, you can do

```
somefunction(someOtherFunction, a, b, c)...
...
```

Later you can access these values:

`a` will be `this[0]`

`b` will be `this[1]`

`c` will be `this[2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.products.find(this.findProducts, [p.id])
findProducts(p) {
  return p.id === this[0];
}
```

above function is the expansion of

```
this.products.find(product=>product.id == p.id)
```

It will iterate through all array element and returns matching product with given p.id

Answer (score 1):

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Syntax) gives some insight into what the second argument to `find` is, namely `thisArg`:

> Object to use as this when executing callback.

So in your example, the callback is `findProducts` and `thisArg` is an array containing one element (which is a slightly weird approach to be honest).

Without `thisArg`, `this` inside `findProducts` would not be that array.

Below is a working demo. Note that without `thisArg`, `this` in `findProducts` is the `window` object. With `thisArg`, it is the second array parameter:

```js
var arr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'a'},
  {id: 2, name: 'b'},
  {id: 3, name: 'c'}, 
  {id: 4, name: 'd'}
];

function findProducts(p) {
  console.log('in findProducts', p);
  console.log(this);
  return p.id === this[0];
}

var f = arr.find(p => findProducts(p));
console.log('without thisArg', f);

f = arr.find(findProducts, [1]);
console.log('with thisArg', f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do is in your **findProducts** fn

```
 findProducts(p) {
   let result = this.products.findIndex(item=>item.id === p.id);
    return result // here the result will contain -1 if value is not present else it will contain some value
  }
```

[read more about find and findIndex](http://2ality.com/2013/12/array-prototype-find.html)